# $psise object in the console Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

is possible to load the $psise object in the console?
I want to open several files in ISE but doing

```
>ise filename
>ise filename2
```

just open the first one. Inside ISE i don't have that problem because i use the $psise object to open the file

```
function qwe($file){
if(-not (Test-Path $file)){
    New-Item -Name $file -ItemType file
}
$filepath = Resolve-Path $file;
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Add($filepath)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$psISE` is property available only in `PowerShell_Ise.exe` environment, so shortly said: **no**.

However, opening two files works for me - it opens a new tab with the file.

Comment: maybe is a bug, i tested several times and I found a pattern. If i apply the code that i say without having the focus in the script pane of ISE a new tab is open. If i have the cursor in the script pane, any subsequent call to ise filenameX is ignored